# Speech recognition in Ubuntu: convert from audio to text

Tags: sound, ffmpeg, convert

I am using the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -ar 16000 -ac 1 file.wav
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav 2> pocketsphinx.log > result.txt
```

All things work fine, but I want to know if there is a script of commands to convert all audio files in a loop for example, and if it is possible to support other languages in pocketsphinx such as Arabic and French and how to do that.

Comment: Please proof-read your question before submitting it. Also, use code tags and other formatting available. See [markdown formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: For loop see [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/1109017)